# Adding ecdf elements to a list in a for cycle with proper name

Tags: r

I'm writing an algorithm that needs to add elements to a list using a for cycle:

```
empirical_cdf=list()

for (j in 1:10) {
  rvar <- rcauchy(n=1000, scale=j)^2
  ecdf_rvar=ecdf(rvar)
  # add ecdf_rvar to the statistic list with the name ecdf_rvar_j?
}
```

So in the end I hope to get a list with 10 ecdfs which can be accessed by $. ecdf is useful for computations and can be plotted, but can't be stored as a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
empirical_cdf=list()

for (j in 1:10) {
  rvar <- rcauchy(n=1000, scale=j)^2
  ecdf_rvar=ecdf(rvar)
  empirical_cdf[[paste0("ecdf_rvar_", j)]] <- ecdf_rvar
}
```

The names of `empirical_cdf` are then

```
> names(empirical_cdf)
 [1] "ecdf_rvar_1"  "ecdf_rvar_2"  "ecdf_rvar_3"  "ecdf_rvar_4"  "ecdf_rvar_5"  "ecdf_rvar_6" 
 [7] "ecdf_rvar_7"  "ecdf_rvar_8"  "ecdf_rvar_9"  "ecdf_rvar_10"
```